# MySQL -- CONDITIONAL GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a 42 million records table, in the following scope:

```
| id |    date    | sid |
+----+------------+-----+
| 01 | 2016-07-09 | 487 |
| 02 | 2016-07-09 | 487 |
| 03 | 2016-07-09 | 487 |
| 04 | 2016-07-09 | 487 |
| 05 | 2016-07-09 | 487 |
| 06 | 2016-07-09 | 753 |
| 07 | 2017-07-01 | 987 |
| 08 | 2017-07-01 | 432 |
| 09 | 2017-07-01 | 432 |
| 10 | 2017-01-13 | 753 |
| 11 | 2017-01-13 | 863 |
| 12 | 2015-01-22 | 255 |
| 13 | 2015-05-22 | 255 |
| 14 | 2015-05-22 | 100 |
| 15 | 2016-07-09 | 487 |
| 16 | 2016-07-09 | 487 |
| 17 | 2016-07-09 | 487 |
| 18 | 2016-07-09 | 487 |
| 19 | 2017-07-01 | 987 |
| 20 | 2017-07-01 | 487 |
| 21 | 2017-01-13 | 753 |
| 22 | 2017-01-13 | 863 |
| 23 | 2015-05-22 | 255 |
| 24 | 2015-05-22 | 100 |
...
```

I need to query this table and get the records grouped by:

- **date**, when **sid** is unique and;
- **date** and after, **sid**, when the table have other sid with this same sid value at this same date

for counting purposes.

In other words, the query needs to return:

```
| id |    date    | sid |
+----+------------+-----+
| 01 | 2016-07-09 | 487 |
| 06 | 2016-07-09 | 753 |
| 07 | 2017-07-01 | 987 |
| 08 | 2017-07-01 | 432 |
| 10 | 2017-01-13 | 753 |
| 11 | 2017-01-13 | 863 |
| 12 | 2015-01-22 | 255 |
| 13 | 2015-05-22 | 255 |
| 14 | 2015-05-22 | 100 |
| 15 | 2016-07-09 | 487 |
| 19 | 2017-07-01 | 987 |
| 20 | 2017-07-01 | 487 |
| 21 | 2017-01-13 | 753 |
| 22 | 2017-01-13 | 863 |
| 23 | 2015-05-22 | 255 |
| 24 | 2015-05-22 | 100 |
...
```

One of my toughts is something like:

```
 SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date(`date`) >= date('2015-01-01') and date(`date`) <= date('2017-07-20') group by CASE WHEN COUNT(`sid` = `sid`) > 0 THEN `sid` END
```

> #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want the `MIN(id)`:

```
SELECT MIN(id), DATE, sid
FROM table
GROUP BY DATE, sid
```

Additional notes:

- Your `WHERE` clause could be simplified to `Date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2017-07-20'`
- Is your column really called `Date`?  That's not a great column name.  It's a keyword and makes the use of `DATE()` and other date functions really confusing.

Comment: **@query**, I'll try your suggestion. **@between**, I don't know why, but, there is a difference in the final count of the query when using between. **@column-name**, Yes, it's called date and, again, yes it may not be a good name or pratice and I realy understand it, but I always keep the use of **`** for column and table names what makes simple to distinguish names from date functions

Comment: @IonS Just wanted to mention the column name - that's up to you.  The `BETWEEN` should work though, although your way is also fine.  Are there timestamps on your dates?

Comment: Yes, I understand and would like to thank you. `\`date\`` is a datetime column

Comment: @IonS Happy to help -- In that case with `BETWEEN`, doing `DATE(date) BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2017-07-20'` should work.  Otherwise a datetime like `'2017-07-20 08:21:00'` would be left out because of the time.  But again, that's just for simplicity's sake, your way is good.